# max method of a list consisting of strings

Tags: python

I am wondering why the result is '4' if I write the following code:

```
lists = ['1','2','3','4']
print(max(lists))
lists.append(5)
print(max(lists))
```

I suppose that the max method of lists converts from `str` to `int` first and then gives me the max of `int`s in the first couple of lines, but this seems untrue if I try the next lines. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: That gives a TypeError because you can't compare strs and ints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it doesn't give you `TypeError` it will return `'4'` for both cases below:

```
list = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
list = ['1', '2', '3', '4', 5]
```

because when comparing objects in python, `str` always > `int` that's why you are getting `'4'` as the max value because it is the highest value among the `strings`

here is an example to prove what I'm saying:

```
>print '1' > 5
True
>print '1' > '5'
False
```

Comment: I understood it. Thank you so much!

Comment: @USUNGYANG Don't forget to accept the answer so other people can see the correct answer when searching for the same question :)

Answer (score 1):

Your list contains strings and you are appending an integer.

lists = ['1', '2', '3', '4', 5]

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

If you had only strings or only int's max will do the comparison as the '>' operator will work. You need to convert the list to all strings or all ints.

```
lists = [int(x) for x in lists]    #by list comprehension
>>> max(lists)                     # lists= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> 5

lists = [str(x) for x in lists]    
>>> max(lists)                     # lists = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
>>> '5'
```

If you have not yet seen list comprehensions it's doing this but much faster and in a single line of code.

```
new_list = []
for x in lists:
    x = int(x)  #convert each individual term to integer objects
    new_list.append(x)
lists = new_list
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
lists = ['1','2','3','4']

print(max(list(map(int, lists))))

lists.append(5)

print(max(list(map(int, lists))))
```